# Getting the could not find method error in android studio while trying to run the app

Tags: android, android-studio

After setting up all the things in the design and code, I tried to run the app but this error pops up, there's no error in the code. I will be glad if someone can help me. Thank you.

Error:

```
Could not find method andorid() for arguments[build_9gmycv9fddo910sgl0ixcpq11$_run_closure1@1e9e8070] on project ':app' of type org. Gradle. Api. Project]
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally that happens because you are using the wrong build.gradle file and mixing the top-level gradel file with the app module gradle file

can you post both of these `build.gradle` files

Answer (score 0):

It might be the gradle issue.

**Click on File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart**